# RunTime Error 13 Type Mismatch VBA Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, type-mismatch

I'm sure this is probably something simple so I apologize ahead of time.  This is actually my first time ever writing VBA and I've come to a problem which I simply can't get my head around how to fix.  I've searched and tried multiple things but still the same problem despite anything I try.

I'm simply opening a new recordset, populating it with values from another table using SQL, retrieving the values from the recordset, then setting the caption on some labels on my form.  My code:

```
Dim oconStudents As ADODB.Connection
Dim orsStudents As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strStudentsSQL As String

Set oconStudents = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
Set orsStudents = New ADODB.Recordset
Set strGetCustIDSQL = _
    "SELECT [CustomerID] FROM [Students Classes] WHERE [Class ID] = " & _
    Me.txtClassID.Value & ";"

orsStudents.Open strGetCustIDSQL, oconStudents, adOpenForwardOnly, _
    adLockReadOnly, adCmdTable

With orsStudents
   If Not orsStudents.EOF Then
       lblStudent1.Caption = orsStudents.Fields.Item(0)
       orsStudents.MoveNext
   End If
End With
```

I run this and I get a runtime error 13 with this line:

```
Set strGetCustIDSQL = _
    "SELECT [CustomerID] FROM [Students Classes] WHERE [Class ID] = " & _
    Me.txtClassID.Value & ";"
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why.  I run the SQL in a query and it returns my values for me properly.  I've changed the adCmdTable to adCmdText and tried adding "#" symbols as well as a host of other characters around the Me.txtClassID.Value section of the SQL string.  Hovering over the SQL string, I can see the right "Class ID =" value (in this case "2") but hovering over the SQL string shows up "=empty".

What simple thing am I neglecting to notice?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Set` part of the assignment for the string is not correct. You only use `Set` for objects (for example ADODB objects). Primitive data types (string, integer, etc.) use simple assignment.

i.e.

```
strGetCustIDSQL = _
    "SELECT [CustomerID] FROM [Students Classes] WHERE [Class ID] = " & _
    Me.txtClassID.Value & ";"
```

Also I don't think the ";" is nessecary when executing SQL from ADODB.

Comment: Wonderful.  I knew it had to be something simple.  Definitely one of those facepalm moments.  Thanks a lot!